# pandas set_index() is creating duplicate columns

Tags: pandas, indexing, timestamp, multi-index

I have to format a dataframe so some code can receive it. It has to be in a specific format. The raw dataframe produced gives me a multi-index format. When I pass to the code it gives an IndexError because it was expecting 1 index.

[Raw dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoZFt.png)

I make a copy of the dataframe and remove the index.

```
ticker_data_2 = ticker_data.copy().reset_index()
```

[Removed index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCRwJ.png)

I need the **timestamp** column to be the index, so I reset the index to be timestamp. But now I have 2 columns named timestamp. Set index is supposed to remove the timestamp column and place it as the index, not make a copy.

```
ticker_data_2.set_index(ticker_data_2['timestamp'], inplace=True)
```

[Duplicate timestamp columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD9D0.png)

How do I fix to make it so only timestamp shows as the index, and not have a second timestamp column.

Comment: How is this
`ticker_data_2 = ticker_data_2.set_index('timestamp')`